# Failed to reset the password/ssh key for virtual machine

Tags: azure, ssh

I am using the `azure portal` to try and create a new `user` with an `ssh key` for a running `VM` by clicking on password reset and then entering a new username with a publish ssh.

the descriptions says

> Providing a new user name will create a new user account with sudo privileges. Providing an existing user name will reset access credentials for that user account.

Each time I click it shows me the error

> Failed to reset the password/ssh key for virtual machine.

without a reason.

Comment: This problem started for me a couple of days ago; no fix yet.  [We aren't the only ones either.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3734ef63-673a-4039-b530-388fdfe9fe76/azure-failed-to-reset-the-password-for-virtual-machine?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows).

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround and it may work in your case. Try changing the configuration of your virtual machine as that will assign you a new box and in the process fix a few configuration issues. Then create a new user and change the configuration again to get your original configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled ProvisionGuestAgent?

Just add `<ProvisionGuestAgent>true</ProvisionGuestAgent>` to Role (in case of using REST API)